# How to compute factor loading manually in CFA

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

How to  calculate factor loading manually in CFA? Can anyone explain it by giving the equation and if so, can you give an example too?

Answer (score 2):

Most CFA models that are used in practice are overidentified. They restrict the observed covarariance and/or mean structure and therefore have > 0 degrees of freedom. In other words, they estimate fewer parameters than there are observed variable variances, covariances, and/or means. For overidentified models with df > 0, there is no closed-form solution for at least some of the parameters of the model. Instead, the parameters are estimated in an iterative process, for example, by using maximum likelihood estimation.

You can manually compute the parameter estimates (including loadings) for saturated (just identified) CFA models, for example, a 1-factor congeneric model with 3 indicators and different loadings between indicators. For that purpose, you would relate the observed variances, covariances, and/or means to the unknown parameters using rules of covariance algebra and rules for expected values (means). Most general/introductory textbooks on structural equation modeling will show you how this works, for example:

Bollen, K. A. (1989). *Structural equations with latent variables*. New York: Wiley.

Raykov, T., & Marcoulides, G. A. (2006). *A first course in structural equation modeling* (2nd. Ed.). Mahwah, NJ: Lawrence Erlbaum Associates.